# Function Arguments with Composition

Tags: python, inheritance

This is an example of *composition from Learn Python the Hard Way.
Example found here: [Example 44](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html) -- see Example 44.e (Under the header "Composition")

When I'm using the call:

```
self.other.implicit()
```

**Does the Child() class utilize the function arguments from the function definition within the Other() class, or does it utilize the arguments from the function definition within the Child() class?**

```
class Other(object):
    def override(self):
         print "OTHER override()"
    def implicit(self):
         print "OTHER implicit()"
    def altered(self):
         print "OTHER altered()"
class Child(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.other = Other()
    def implicit(self):
         self.other.implicit()
    def override(self):
         print "CHILD override()"
    def altered(self):
         print "CHILD, BEFORE OTHER altered()"
         self.other.altered()
         print "CHILD, AFTER OTHER altered()"

son = Child()
son.implicit()
son.override()
son.altered()
```

Comment: The code you are showing us is the example of composition, not Inheritance.

Comment: Python doesn't have function prototypes, so functions are overridden by name.

Comment: @jgomo3 I apologize for misrepresenting my question initially, I updated it to reflect my initial curiosity, hopefully worded better. I'm mainly just trying to figure out how the function arguments are handled in this situation. Is there a hierarchy of arguments? Do the arguments have to be the same to reference the function in the other class? In the case that they are different, how are they handled on the call `self.other.implicit()` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does the Child() class inherit the function arguments from the function definition within the Other() class, or does it utilize the arguments from the function definition within the Child() class?

They both have the same arguments - one positional argument (which is used for `self`). So, there's no difference between the functions in that respect.

> Does the Child() class inherit the function arguments from the function definition within the Other() class

`Child` does not inherit from `Other`; it inherits from `object`, so there will be no inheritance of any sort.

Comment: in terms of function arguments, say that the definition for `implicit()` in the `Child()` class had different function arguments than that of `implicit()` in `Other(), would there be a hierarchy of argument precedence or would the arguments have to match?

Comment: @black_bird There's no inheritance, as my answer already explains.

Comment: I don't believe you're understanding my question or I'm not completely understanding your answer. What I'm trying to ask is how the functions arguments are handled in the two definitions for `implicit()`. Whether or not it's called one thing or another, I'm just want to know how the arguments have to be set up in this case in order to properly call the functions with more than just the `self` argument called.

Comment: @blackbird literally however you like. The only rule is that the first argument gets the self object. Beyond that, do whatever you like. There's no relationship between these classes except whatever you create by one callin the methods of the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Other(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
   def implicit(self, arg1, arg2):
        print arg1
        print arg2

class Child(Other):
    def __init__(self):
       pass
    def implicit(self, arg1):
       print arg1

Other().implicit(1, 2)
Child().implicit(3)


Output:
1
2
3
```

If you are considering above case then arguments does not matter in python
Python is dynamic language so you are not having rules like Java for overriding 
Simply It will match arguments w.r.t. current object method on which it is invoking
if it fails to find such method in current object it will look for parent object

```
class Other(object):
    def __init__(self):
       pass
    def implicit(self, arg1, arg2):
       print arg1
       print arg2

class Child(Other):
    def __init__(self):
       pass

Child().implicit(3) 
# will raise -> TypeError: implicit() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
# as child does not have implicit method, we will look for method in parent(Other)  
# which accepts 3 args (including self)

Child().implicit(1, 2) # this will work
output:
1
2
```

In your example implicit in Other and implicit in Child are two different functions on two different objects,